# Как создать jar-ник проекта, использующего сторонний jar-файлы?

Tags: java, jar

Как создать jar-ник проекта, использующего сторонний jar-файлы?

Comment: Так же, как обычный.

Comment: да, но где должен находится сторонний jar-файл?

Comment: Где угодно, если это местонахождение входит в classpath.